# Using loop to add to docx.js Document

Tags: javascript, loops, docx

I am using docx.js to create a Word document from text that is entered into a textarea. I have created an array (arrayOfLines) which splits the textarea contents at each new line.

I now want to add this array to the Document using a loop function, and the code I am using does not seem to work. Hoping someone might be able to help, as I could not find many answers here so far. Apologies if I haven't been clear, this is my first question. Thank you.

```
    saveEssay () {
   var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById('textArea').value.split('\n');
    

    const buildParagraph = async()=>{
      let paragraphArray = []
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLines.length; i++){
        paragraphArray.push(new Paragraph({text: arrayOfLines[i].text }))
      }
    return paragraphArray;
  };


    let doc = new Document({
    sections: [
      {
        headers: {
                default: new Header({
                    children: [new Paragraph("Page heading")],
                }),
            },
        children: [
          new Paragraph({ text: "My Essay", heading: HeadingLevel.HEADING_2 }),
          buildParagraph() // paragraphs are not coming through 
        ]
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't see any particular reason why your buildParagraph function is declared as `async`. Did you try with a regular (non-async) function instead?

Comment: I copied and pasted the async function as it was recommended in another answer, but changing it to a regular function has not yielded a successful output, I'm not sure why, any other ideas? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

According to your post, there are basicly two corrections that you should make :

1. The arrayOfLines item is already a text string:

```js
paragraphArray.push(new Paragraph({text: arrayOfLines[i]}))
```

2. The return of buildParagraph() function should be expanded:

```js
children: [
    new docx.Paragraph({ text: 'My Essay', heading: docx.HeadingLevel.HEADING_2 }),
    ...buildParagraph(),
],
```

p.s. As comment stated, its better to replace `async` buildParagraph function with a regular one because its all sync execution. However, async function also works, since [docx.js iterates over children via `for...of` statement](https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx/blob/master/src/file/paragraph/paragraph.ts#L64). Very considerate haha.

This is an online codepen demo in your case if any one needs :D

https://codepen.io/DearVikki/pen/XWqxyYZ